# I Need Someone to Explain the Query Conditions

Tags: java, mysql, max, conditional-statements, min

I know this statement are Conditions but can anyone explain how is it work and what is mean exactly ??

what this <> mean

```
" AND (FromDate is null or FromDate >= ?) "
" AND (Status is null or Status <> 'Canceled')"
```

and those are almost the same what the different between them ?

```
(min(FromDate) >= ? AND max(ToDate) <= ? ) OR "
" (min(FromDate) >= ? AND max(ToDate) <= ? ) "
```

Comment: `<>` is "greater than AND less than", a.k.a "not equal to". note sure what you mean with the second. The two condition sets are identical. `p OR p` is pointless duplication.

Comment: `<>` is old-school for `!=` and still enjoys life in Excel spreadsheets which inherited it from [Lotus 1-2-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_1-2-3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<> is SQl's version of `does not equal` whereas <= is `less than or equal to` and >= is `greater than or equal to`. So in answer to your question, the from date has to be equal too the set date or greater than it and the status does not equal cancelled

Answer (score 0):

`<>` stands for `!=` (does not equal to). It's pretty old school - most newer languages do not use that.

Also, `?` (a question mark) represents a parameter in a query. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727688/what-does-a-question-mark-represent-in-sql-queries).

Comment: And Excel. And Basic (including VB). And Pascal (including Delphi). And probably others too :-)