# Escape an '@' character in a SQL query / ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, activerecord

How do I escape an '@' query in a SQL query.

I am using ActiveRecord (3).

```
suite_scenarios = Scenario.where(suite_id: suite_id)
tag_pair = ["@regression","@daily_feature"]

tag_pair_scenarios = suite_scenarios.where("metadata LIKE '%#{tag_pair[0]}%'").where("metadata LIKE '%#{tag_pair[1]}%'")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31982435) explaining how to construct ILIKE queries with placeholder conditions, it seems you can construct your query like this:

```
suite_scenarios.
  where("metadata LIKE '%' || ? || '%'", tag_pair[0]).
  where("metadata LIKE '%' || ? || '%'", tag_pair[1]")
```

This has the added benefit of protecting you from SQL injection, in case `tag_pair` comes from user input (form params).