# getting result of select 1 query in PreparedStatement in JAVA

Tags: java, sql, select, prepared-statement

I am trying to get the result of `SELECT 1` query using PreparedStatement. I am unable to get the result. Since the select 1 query result has no column name, so how can I retrieve the resultant column value.

```
Connection conn = DB.getconnnection();
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select 1 from tbl_user where username = ? and password = ?");
ps.setString(1,txtUsername.getText());
ps.setString(2,String.valueOf(txtPassword.getPassword()));
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
String status=rs.getString("");
System.out.println(status);
conn.close();
```

I referred the code from java tutorial, I can not understand why is there `?` in the query statement (`select 1 from tbl_user where username = ? and password = ?`). Please clarify.

Comment: @kayaman How is this question duplicate from the question you said. Better you read the question properly. Please remove this tag.

Comment: You should do if(rs.next()){ int val = rs.getInt(1); }

Comment: `?` is a placeholder that you replace with the required username in `ps.setString(1,txtUsername.getText());` More info here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html You can retrieve a column result value using its index `rs.getString(1)`More info here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html#retrieve_rs

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727688/what-does-a-question-mark-represent-in-sql-queries) answers part of your question.

Comment: The duplicate explains very well what's the difference with a regular statement (i.e. a regular SQL query), and `PreparedStatement`. It even answers this question, so it's a duplicate. You can use `getString(1)` to get columns based on index instead of name, that's very basic stuff.