# Unable to use query.filter_by in Flask-SQLAlchemy with keyword arguments or variables

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am working on a blog application in Flask and have been struggling to find a way to wrap up some code that will filter blog posts by categorical attributes (or tags) that users will add to their posts. For example, the code below is meant to return all posts that have been marked as 'anonymous'.

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        anonymous = form.anonymous.data
        flash('Here are your search results!')
        return redirect(url_for('search_results', anonymous=anonymous))
    return render_template('search.html', title='Search', form=form)

@app.route('/search_results/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search_results():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    anonymous = request.args.get('anonymous')
    posts = Post.query.filter_by(anonymous=anonymous).paginate(page, app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'],                                    False).items
    return render_template('search_results.html', title='Search Results', posts=posts)
```

As the code above shows, I would like to be able to use `request.args.get('anonymous')` to retrieve whether the user is searching for anonymous posts and then use `Post.query.filter_by(anonymous=anonymous)` to find all posts that match this description. This works without a problem when I use `Post.query.filter_by(anonymous=True)`, as you can see below.

```
print(Post.query.filter_by(anonymous=True))
posts = Post.query.filter_by(anonymous=True).paginate(page, app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'], False).items
print(posts)

SELECT post.id AS post_id, post.body AS post_body, post.image_name AS post_image_name, post.image AS post_image, post.anonymous AS post_anonymous, post.timestamp AS post_timestamp, post.user_id AS post_user_id
FROM post
WHERE post.anonymous = 1
[<Post my first post!>, <Post new post!>]
```

However, when I pass a variable to query.filter_by it does not appear to be inserting the value into the parameter. The result of the query is an empty set, even though the value of 'anonymous' is definitely set to True.

```
anonymous = request.args.get('anonymous')
print(anonymous)
print(Post.query.filter_by(anonymous=anonymous))
posts = Post.query.filter_by(anonymous=anonymous).paginate(page, app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'], False).items
print(posts)

True
SELECT post.id AS post_id, post.body AS post_body, post.image_name AS post_image_name, post.image AS post_image, post.anonymous AS post_anonymous, post.timestamp AS post_timestamp, post.user_id AS post_user_id
FROM post
WHERE post.anonymous = ?
[]
```

What I get in the query is the condition `WHERE post.anonymous = ?` instead of `WHERE post.anonymous = 1 (or 0)` which is what was hoping to see. Below is the code I have been trying:

My guess is that SQL-Alchemy simply does not support using a variable as a placeholder for the value I want to query with. Otherwise there may be some syntax that I am not aware of that I need to use to make this work, which is what I am looking into at this point. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: The `?` is a so called placeholder, where the driver or the database system will place the actual value when the query is executed. What the print shows you is that the query itself is correct up to that point. Check that the data and the argument are as well.

Comment: Thanks Ilja. I tried testing to make sure the value from 'anonymous' was indeed available for the query and everything seems to be working fine (I've updated my original post with the code I used to test this). It appears that there is some limitation in what query.filter_by can accept, which I am still looking into at this point. I find it strange that the code above may not work by design for SQL-Alchemy so perhaps I am missing something else.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! "However it seems that I cannot pass a variable to query.filter_by and it is not working for me with keyword arguments either." Can you be more specific? You have shown that all of the inputs going into `filter_by` appear to be correct (as was mentioned, seeing a `?` rather than your value in the SQL output is expected behavior). However, it's not easy to see from your samples why you believe `filter_by` is not working. Is it throwing an error? Is it returning a result you believe to be correct? Being specific here will help us determine what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome message Mark. The `?` in the query seems to indicate that the values in 'anonymous' are not being incorporated as I had originally thought they would be. The result of the query is an empty set `[]` which means that nothing was retrieved (due it seems to the fact that the value in the 'anonymous' variable is not being recognized by the query.filter_by request).

Comment: @OliverMcCarthy I know it seems like the `?` indicates that it's not working correctly, or that it's an error, but I believe you're mistaken. It's quite common for SQL client libraries to generate queries with placeholders like `?` instead of the actual value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727688/what-does-a-question-mark-represent-in-sql-queries for more info. My recommendation is to write the SQL query you expect SQLA to be generating, and run that against your DB. Let us know what that query is and what the expected result is, and then what you got instead from SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @MarkHildreth Thanks vm Mark, really appreciate the guidance here. I've updated the original post with the info you were asking about as I understand it. As you can see when I run the query with anonymous set to True explicitly, everything works as I would like. It's only when I try to pass a variable to the query.filter_by function that it seems to break down. Now that I know that it is expecting a parameter I am going to look into how I may be able to provide that so the query retrieves the expected value.

Comment: Btw. from the debug prints you had in the question before I saw that you did not convert `anonymous` from string to a boolean before passing it to the query. From using `?` I would guess you are using SQLite. SQLite is a bit special in that it uses dynamic typing and weaker typing in general, and so it is perfectly ok to compare `0 = 'False'`, but the result is no match as you have noticed.

Comment: Great catch Ilja. That appears to have been the issue as I converted 'True' and 'False' to 1 and 0  and it now works properly!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments above the issue was that the value in anonymous was converted from a boolean to a string when it was passed from the search route to the search_results route. I used a quick if-else statement to convert the value back to boolean and everything works as expected now.

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        anonymous = form.anonymous.data
        print(anonymous)
        print(type(anonymous))
        flash('Here are your search results!')
        return redirect(url_for('search_results', anonymous=anonymous))
    return render_template('search.html', title='Search', form=form)

127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2020 01:56:16] "GET /search HTTP/1.1" 200 -
True
<class 'bool'>

@app.route('/search_results/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search_results():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    anonymous = request.args.get('anonymous')
    print(anonymous)
    print(type(anonymous))
    if anonymous == 'True':
        anonymous = bool(1)
    else:
        anonymous = bool(0)
    print(anonymous)
    print(type(anonymous))
    posts = Post.query.filter_by(anonymous=anonymous).paginate(page, app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'], False).items
    print(posts)
    return render_template('search_results.html', title='Search Results', posts=posts)

127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2020 01:56:30] "POST /search HTTP/1.1" 302 -
True
<class 'str'>
1
<class 'bool'>
[<Post my first post!>, <Post new post!>]
```