# How to get a job parameter in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

A source system switched from Neteeza to Snowflake and our query is breaking.

We had a job parameter as a date (similar to [What does a question mark represent in SQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727688/what-does-a-question-mark-represent-in-sql-queries))

as a ?. The ? seems to longer work and this document didn't help me: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#viewing-the-parameters-and-their-values

Comment: When you say "source system" do you mean that your system, issuing the query, is not Snowflake? Please can you provide more detail about your architectural setup and include the code for the job that you are trying to execute

Comment: @NickW source system is Snowflake and was Neteeza. 

The part of the query that fails is: 

```where cast (Start_Time as date) > TO_DATE(?,'YYYY-MM-DD')```

Since the parameter ? is not accepted.

Comment: Yes, but you must have a process to pass a value into that parameter when the query is run. What is that process? What/where is that process running?

Comment: @NickW The service utilizes Pentaho and is invoked on a Windows server with the statement:
```iex "C:\Users\user\Pentaho\Pan.bat /file:c:\Users\user/Pentaho\kettles\itg_session.ktr '/param:`"START_TIME=$qStartTime`"' /level:Basic"```

I am confused though how that matters with getting the actual parameter in the query.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear but I'm trying to get you to explain how the SQL statement is being executed and, as you've said in your comment, want you've provided doesn't help with that. For example, a Pentaho process could be replacing the parameter with the actually value and the resolved SQL statement passed to Snowflake for execution; alternatively, the SQL could be part of a stored procedure in Snowflake and the ? represents a parameter being passed to the stored proc. Unless you actually explain what processes you are running and what they are doing, it's going to difficult to help you.