# '?' in where condition Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I am try to get the relating to 'comment' model 'commentsRating' model.

```
 return $this->hasMany(commentRating::class,'comment_id','id')->toSql();
```

And get the following output:

```
 "select * from `comment_ratings` where `comment_ratings`.`comment_id` = ? and `comment_ratings`.`comment_id` is not null"
```

Comment model is:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'body',
        'user_id',
        'item_id'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'user_id' => 'integer',
        'item_id' => 'integer',
    ];

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Items::class, 'id');
    }

    public function ratings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(commentRating::class,'comment_id','id')->toSql();
    }

}
```

And the rating model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class commentRating extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $fillable = [
        'comment_id',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function comment()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Comment');
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: After having read the title, I would assume that you care about the `?` in the query? That's a placeholder for a prepared statement, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727688/what-does-a-question-mark-represent-in-sql-queries

Comment: Why exactly did you put a `->toSql()` to that relation? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to debug and got confuse when got '?' in sql query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because laravel by default bind the variables to the query, you can use:

```php
return $this->hasMany(commentRating::class,'comment_id','id')->dd();
```

this will return two values, the query with `?`, and the array of values to bind

Comment: can this output be saved in variable.Seeems like this works like print_r and my function doesnot return anything so i get 500 err

Comment: it just die and dump the query

Comment: if you want to add it to a variable try this `$sql = $query->toSql(); $bindings = $query->getBindings();` this will return 2 variables, the query and the bindings

Comment: and btw, laravel do so to avoid sql injection

Comment: thx u for help,seems like this bilds its ok,i am just try to debug that query