# CActiveRecord::find() doesn't give one record or object. Trying to get property from non-object

Tags: php, orm, yii

`<td><?= PersoonHasStdtaak::model()->findByPk(array('idPlanning' => $modelPlanning->idPlanning, 'idStdTaak' => $modelStdtaak->idStdTaak))->idPersoon0->Naam ?></td>`

I've got this. Somehow when I let it just print it without the `idPersoon0->Naam` it prints regulary a composite primary key in this form `#-#-#` for example `1-2-3` where `1` represents the `Person` `2` represents the `Planning` and `3` represents the `Taak`.

Why does it give me the "`Trying to get property from non-object.`"?

Comment: "idPersoon0" is a field in the database? cause if idPersoon is an array with all the ids then to acces its value you should do "idPersoon[0]->Naam"

Comment: I'ts a property holding the whole `Persoon` object. According to other posts on this should be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567686/yii-cactiverecord-find

Comment: May be try to do 2 lines:
$model = PersoonHasStdtaak::model()->findByPk(array('idPlanning' => $modelPlanning->idPlanning, 'idStdTaak' => $modelStdtaak->idStdTaak));
$model->idPersoon0->Naam;
Just to see if the error comes from the first one or the second one. Then it'll be easier to determine what causes the "Trying to get property from non-object"

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yes I've done that, but still got the same error. Would be nice if it said: "Cannot retrieve property from null-object" but i've found it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.. Stupid mistake by "ME"

I was looping through something where it's possible that there is no record with those combination of primary keys. Therefore it returns `NULL`. And from a `NULL-object` its not possible to get any properties :) (doH)

Good luck for anyone finding this. Look out if it returns a `NULL object`.