# Laravel Query Builder: whereExists translates condition clause to question mark

Tags: laravel, query-builder

If I have the following query built using the Query Builder:

```
$q = DB::table('Products')->whereExist(function ($q)
{
    $q->select(DB::raw(1))
      ->from('tags_products')
      ->where('products.PorductId', '=',  'tags_products.ProductID');
});
```

The translated SQL using `$q->toSql();` that is:

```
select * from `Products` where `exist` = (select 1 from `tags_products` where `products`.`ProductID` = ?)
```

Apparently, the Query Builder translates **tags_products.ProductID** to **?**.

Why does it become **"?"** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Jared Eitnier very well pointed out, Laravel uses PDO to bind the parameters you pass to the Query Builder methods. However, because when you use `where` the third parameter represents the value, Laravel will not treat it as a column unless you explicitly tell it to, otherwise it will treat `'tags_products.ProductID'` as a regular string value. So you have two options here:

**1.** Use `DB::raw()` to let the Query Builder know that the value is not a string that requires escaping:

```
->where('products.PorductId', '=', DB::raw('tags_products.ProductID'));
```

**2.** Use `whereRaw()` which will allow you to write a raw SQL statement:

```
->whereRaw('products.PorductId = tags_products.ProductID');
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Was getting a "sqlstate[22p02]: invalid text representation: 7 error: invalid input syntax for integer:" error

Answer (score 0):

These are mysql `prepared statements`.

See [What is the question mark's significance in MySQL at "WHERE column = ?"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675010/what-is-the-question-marks-significance-in-mysql)

Laravel uses mysql's PDO.