# Group result set by combination of multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have table called negotiations like this

```
id    seller_id  buyer_id property_id
1        4           190      33123
2        4           190      33123
3        5           191      34000
4        5           191      34000
5        6           200      35000
```

I can fetch all by doing:

```
Negotiation.all
```

I want fetch everything, but grouped by `seller_id`-`buyer_id`-`property_id` combination. This in the above example I want to return three groups.

Is this possible in my rails application?

Comment: What do you mean by "grouped by seller_id-buyer_id-property_id"? I can see the three groups but what would the result look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) :

```
Negotiation.all.group_by do |item| 
  [item.seller_id, item.buyer_id, item.property_id]
end
```

Comment: wow can't believe this wasn't asked on SO before

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could achieve this creating a scope that takes some args that you define in your `Negotiation` model. I am not 100% on the correct syntax, but believe this approach is the most appropriate.

```rb
scope :seller_buyer_property_combo, ->(seller, buyer, property) { 
   where("negotiations.seller_id = ? AND 
          negotiations.buyer_id = ? AND
          negotiations.property_id = ?", seller.id, buyer.id, property.id) }
```

---

This syntax follows the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675010/what-is-the-question-marks-significance-in-mysql-at-where-column):

In Rails for example, the question mark is replaced by an argument given by a variable of the library's programming language (Ruby), e.g.:

```
Table.where("column = ?", "value")
```

and it automatically quotes arguments to avoid bugs and SQL injection, generating a statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE column = 'value';
```

The quoting would save us in case of something like:

```
Table.where("column = ?", "; INJECTION")
```

---

If you want to reuse the combinations and there are not so many perhaps you can just hard-code the combinations into a few different scopes (alleviating the needs for the args which may cause confusion in the ordering etc.)